# Eclipse Plugin for JAVA Ressource Bundle String completition

Tags: java, eclipse, localization, eclipse-plugin

Is there any plugin for eclipse, which allows me to autocomplete (CTRL+SPACE) a string from my localization ressource bundle?

Or is there any other good practice for an easy localization?

My current status. It is working, but I think there may is an easier way.

This is my localization class:

```
/**
 * Singelton class to provide localization Strings
 * 
 * @author Andreas Freitag
 * 
 */
public class Localization {
  private static Localization instance = null;
  private Options options;
  private ResourceBundle captions;

  private Localization() {
    options = Options.getInstance();
    Locale locale = new Locale(options.getLanguage());
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale(options.getLanguage()));
    captions = ResourceBundle.getBundle("res.localization.localizationMessages", locale);
  }

  /**
   * Getter for the singelton localization (thread-safe)
   * */
  public synchronized static Localization getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
      synchronized (Localization.class) {
        instance = new Localization();
      }
    }
    return instance;
  }

  /**
   * A little convenience for getting the Localized strings
   * 
   * @param name
   *          of the element to search for
   * @return the localized String
   */
  public String getString(String name) {
    return captions.getString(name);
  }

}
```

The localized strings I access via `Localization.getInstance.getString("Infoframe.Example");`

Comment: IntelliJ just does this out of the box - no plugin needed.  Time to upgrade your IDE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will take a look at it. But this was not my question. Due to the fact that we are working in a team, with shared configs in eclipse, it is (for this project) not possible to change the IDE.

Comment: I'm not sure where you want Eclipse to help here. What has that class got to do with your question?

Comment: The class is only for information, maybe there is another good solution for localization. But you are right, the main question is: Is there a plugin for eclipse, to autocomplete the ressource string (in this case: Infoframe.Example)

Comment: Oh, it's always possible.  You're just saying that it's not likely...your loss.  How many other ways are you fighting Eclipse?

Comment: sorry for another indirect answer, but if use c10n then you won't need a plugin: https://github.com/rodionmoiseev/c10n/wiki/Overview

Comment: Thanks for your tip regarding c10n...it looks very nice!

Comment: @AndreasFreitag Just an FYI: actually it has support for ResourceBundle mapping, so instead of storing translations in the source, it can fetch translations from specified bundle behind the scenes. However, it will generate its own translation keys, which you can't control at the moment. Bundle support is not quite official yet, that's why it's not on the wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it'll provide you auto-completion, but for a java project you can run `Source > Externalize Strings...` to get a wizard that will collect any strings you want into a resource bundle for you and replace their occurrences with calls to load the ResourceBundle property key.

For eclipse plugins they use tooling and subclasses of `org.eclipse.osgi.util.NLS` to provide a class where the public fields match the resource keys (so you get auto-completion).